# Override virtualbox default temp directory

Tags: linux, virtualbox, environment-variables, ubuntu-18.04

My /tmp location is a small size mount point. I want to import ova file to virtualbox.

I could not find a configuration option for this solution in the virtualbox. I tried these solutions, but none succeeded.

```
TMPDIR=/other/temp vboxmanage import IE11\ -\ Win7.ova
TMP=/other/temp vboxmanage import IE11\ -\ Win7.ova
TEMP=/other/temp vboxmanage import IE11\ -\ Win7.ova
```

Additional info:

Target drive path (virtual box disks) is on the large mount. Virtualbox must use the temp directory in the import process.

```
mount --bind /other/tmp /tmp/.vbox-smarton-ipc  # virtual box starting error...
```

Comment: The "temp directory" may not be the correct terminology here. Did you mean the folder where VirtualBox stores all the VM file (vhd, vmdk, xml etc)?

Comment: Is the current temp folder located on the same drive as it is installed? maybe changing the installation to the drive you want the temp to be would do the trick. Just a guess though.

Comment: Biswapriyo: temp folder is the system temp folder. Vm files (disks, xmls, etc.) are another mount point with enough storage space. Actually, that's why I don't understand it either, because VM files and all that kind of thing are at a big mount point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The "temp directory" may not be the correct terminology here. Did you mean the folder where VirtualBox stores all the VM file (vhd, vmdk, xml etc)? – Biswapriyo

For some reason, he ignored the destination paths of the other disks. I bind /home/smarton/VirtualBox VMs to large mount point, and it's work!